# Marshal sql.NullString with omitempty

Tags: go

How is one supposed to not render the null sql.NullString if it is not valid? - http://play.golang.org/p/pzSWS9vE0J

It doesn't seem to be working with omitempty struct tag and I can't quite figure out what to return from the MarshalJSON such that omitempty will be honored

```
type NS struct {
    sql.NullString
}

func (ns *NS) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Println("Marshaling json for NS")
    if ns.String == "" && !ns.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(ns.String)
}

type A struct {
   RStr string `json:rstr,omitempty"`
   Str NS `json:"str,omitempty"`
}


func main() {
    a := A{RStr: "rstr"}
    s, _ := json.Marshal(&a)
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that, however you can always use a pointer instead : http://play.golang.org/p/b4Q7YgpUa-

```
func main() {
    a := A{"rstr", &sql.NullString{"Test", true}}
    s, err := json.Marshal(&a)
    fmt.Println(string(s), err)
    a = A{}
    fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal(s, &a))
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", a.RStr, a.Str.String)
    a = A{RStr: "rstr"}
    s, err = json.Marshal(&a)
    fmt.Println(string(s), err)
}
```

The reason why a pointer makes a difference from http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal:

> -the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.
>
> > **The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero.**

Comment: I have the same question, and using a pointer does not help much. I am using the *sql.NullString type as a receiver to a row scan. The pointer value will be set by scan, thus omitempty fails and the k/v pair is still populated into the JSON as k: null. What's the best solution to prevent the k/v from showing up in the JSON? Iterating over the fields in the struct before marshaling to JSON, and setting the pointer values to nil when the Value() method returns nil, nil?